# Regular expression with even sum of a's and b's

Tags: regex, regular-language

Hello I've browser a trivia site about cs and one of the question was to construct a regular expression with two digits eg (1,0) that generate strings that have even number of 0's and 1's. To be clearer if we had m 1's and n 0's then m+n should be even. Can there exist such a regular expression? I've been brainstorming for a while and I cannot find any regex to match this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is such a regular expression.

```
([01]{2})*
```

Self-explanatory.

Comment: In python: `re.match(r'([01]{2})*', '1000')`, `re.match(r'([01]{2})*', '0111')`

Comment: Call me noob but I know the regular expressions from theory of computation, can you trasform this to such a form?

Comment: Well if hypothetically this is CS homework you'd write it as `((0|1)(0|1))*`

Comment: haha it's not homework. I've graudated last year, but do you mean    ( (0|1)(0|1) )* cause what you've written will generate a string like 0101010101

Comment: You mean you don't want to accept `0101010101`? That has `m=5` and `n=5` so `m+n=10` is even.

Comment: I haven't seen the edit in your comment! Now I figured it out. Thx a lot for your time!